# Second Fundamental Form of Torus

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to prove that the mean curvature vector of the flat Torus $T^n=S^1\times S^1\times ...\times S^1\subset\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is zero. But my calculations show me to the contrary that the mean curvature doesn't vanishes.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual embedding $x(s,t)=(\cos s, \sin s,\cos t,\sin t)$ does induce a *flat* metric. However, this does not mean that the second fundamental form vanishes. For example, the cylinder $x(s,t)=(\cos s,\sin s,t)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ is flat (i.e., has Gaussian curvature $0$) but does not have vanishing second fundamental form. Vanishing second fundamental form would mean a totally geodesic submanifold. You're asking for less ... that the mean curvature (*vector*) vanish. But, no, the flat torus in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ does *not* have zero mean curvature vector, as it is not a minimal submanifold. Now there are minimal embeddings of, for example, the torus $T^2$ in $S^3$, as opposed to $\mathbb R^4$.